# Euler's totient theorem

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that it follows from Euler's totient theorem that if $r\equiv s \pmod {\varphi(n)}$ then $a^r \equiv a^s \pmod n$ where $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

We know from Euler's totient theorem that $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$, but how do I relate that to the fact that $r\equiv s \pmod {\varphi(n)}$?

Comment: Hint:  if a $a^r = x \mod n $ what is $a^{r-\phi (n)}\mod n $?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Since $r\equiv s \pmod {\varphi(n)}$ then $r-s=t\phi(n)$ for some $t\in \mathbb{N}$, then use it in the Euler's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG assume that $r \ge s$. So, $r = s + k\varphi(n)$ where $k \ge 0$.

$a^r \equiv a^{s + k\varphi(n)} \equiv a^s \cdot (a^{\varphi(n)})^k \equiv a^s \cdot 1^k \equiv a^s \pmod n$